# Drop columns with a 'NA' header from data frames in a list?

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames that are pulled in from an Excel file.  Some of the columns in the data frames have are named 'NA', contain no data, and are useless; therefore, I would like to drop them.  The list contains 9 data frames and most have columns with 'NA' as their title.

Through multiple iterations, R has returned an error or warning.  Including:

```
all_list <- all_list[!is.na(colnames(all_list))]
Warning message:
In is.na(colnames(all_list)) :
is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

The above did not serve it's intended purpose, as the NA columns are still in each data frame.

```
all_list <- lapply(all_list, function(x){
colnames(x) <- x[!is.na(colnames(x))]
return(x)
})
```

This seems closer to the intended output, but reformats the data frame columns to be filled with NA's instead.

Here is a sample of my data showcasing the aforementioned NA's:

```
str(all_list)
List of 8
$ Retail        :'data.frame':  305 obs. of  25 variables:
$ NA                    : chr [1:305] NA "Variable" "Variable" "Variable" ...
$ TIMEPERIOD            : chr [1:305] NA "41640" "41671" "41699" ...
```

Edit: In case it wasn't clear, these blank columns filled with NA are the result of formatting within Excel for the sake of spacing; however, they serve no purpose for analysis within R.

Comment: `all_list[colnames(all_list) != 'NA']`?

Comment: I think you need to ask yourself how you ended up with those columns in the first place.

Comment: @RichScriven these columns are the result of empty columns in the Excel file.  They are used for spacing/formatting there, but serve no purpose for analysis within R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close to solution. A slight change in `function` used with `lapply` will take you to expected result.

The `lapply` traverses through each dataframe and your function needs to `subset` columns which names are `not equal` to `NA`.

```
all_list < lapply(all_list, function(x){
  x[,colnames(x)  != "NA"]
})

# Verify changed data all_list
all_list[[1]]
#   col1 col2
# 1    g    x
# 2    j    z
# 3    n    p
# 4    u    o
# 5    e    b
```

**Data:**

```
set.seed(1)

df1 <- data.frame(sample(letters, 5), sample(letters, 5), 1:5,
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(df1) <- c("col1","col2","NA")
df2 <- data.frame(sample(letters, 5), sample(letters, 5), 11:15,
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(df2) <- c("col1","col2","NA")
df3 <- data.frame(sample(letters, 5), sample(letters, 5), rep(NA, 5),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(df3) <- c("col1","col2","NA")
df4 <- data.frame(sample(letters, 5), sample(letters, 5), rep(NA, 5),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(df4) <- c("col1","col2","NA")

all_list <- list(df1,df2,df3,df4)
#check data
all_list[[1]]
#  col1 col2 NA
#1    g    x  1
#2    j    z  2
#3    n    p  3
#4    u    o  4
$5    e    b  5

# all_list[[2]], all_list[[3]] and all_list[[4]] contains similar values
```

Comment: Hi!  When utilizing this solution, I receive an "undefined columns selected" error.  Could this be the result of these columns being actual "NA" rather than character NA?

Comment: @Franchise you can try `x[ , !is.na(colnames(x))]` . If it doesnt works then please share your sample `.xls`